# Аngular JS  $rootScope

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, подскажите плз почему переменную $rootScope.$test в консоле выдаёт undefined?
А вот если брать общий console.log($rootScope); то инфа $test есть.

```
var myApp = angular.module('SiteApp',[]); 
myApp.run(['$rootScope','$http', function($rootScope,$http){ 
     $http({method: 'post', url: '/index.php/ajax/session'}).success(function(data) {                           
        $rootScope.$test = data;
    });
$rootScope.$post = 123;
}]).directive('myDialog', function($rootScope) {
        return  { 
                restrict: 'E',
                template: function () { 
                        console.log($rootScope.test);                           
                            return "";  
                    }           
                };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы делаете [асинхронный](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn9Jh/2/) запрос и на момент когда ваша дериктива преобразуется, данных ещё нет.

Comment: Cпасибо, что пояснили.